# Split transformation steps based on Parameter in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, etl, data-integration

I have a transformation with a boolean parameter. If the parameter is 1, I want the data to flow through one transformation path. But if the parameter is 0, I want it to flow through a different transformation path. What step can I possibly use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Filter Rows" step in PDI. Check the image below:

[image]

Give the parameter value as "1" or "0" in the filter rows section. Also properly assign the path for both true and false conditions.

For more you can check this [link](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Filter+Rows).

Hope it helps :)